# Can not install hera on Dell Inspiron 3782

Tags: system-installation, release-hera, dell

I am trying to install eOS 5.1 on my Dell Inspiron 3782.

I could create the USB drive on the very same laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 pre installed, I could boot with USB but All I see is the desktop screen and nothing happens. The funny thing is that I can use Function keys and they work (I can tune the volume and I can hear the sound, I can tune the keyboard backlight and the screen).

The dock goes back and forth, and I tried some keyboard shortcuts but nothing happens.

Can you help me or should I restore Ubuntu?!

[image: stuck desktop]

[EDIT]

I found some additional commands to use in the grub menu but no luck. I had my laptop restored to Ubuntu 18.04 and I find out that I could install elementary OS desktop, but it is not a smooth OS, maybe my (cheap) laptop is not capable to run Elementary OS. Switching back to Ubuntu with Wayland is the better option for me.

Comment: Hello, you should be able to run elementary os if you can run ubuntu since they need the same requirements more or less. Your PC should be capable of running elementary OS. Elementary sometimes has a bug in which the desktop takes a while to load, but you can make it faster if you press Ctrl+Alt+F1 and then Ctrl+Alt+F7.

Comment: Thank you. I will try and let you know. BTW what happens exactly when I press those keyboard combinations? Thank you!

Comment: It goes to a terminal window called tty and then goes back to your desktop. For some reason it works.

Comment: Can you install `inxi` like that `sudo apt install inxi` and laucnh this command `inxi -F` and add the output in your question?